# Why is ] used for tag navigation?

Tags: key-bindings, tags, history-of, original-vi

Several of the commands for [browsing programs with tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags) use <kbd>]</kbd>.

- Is there a mnemonic for this?
- Why was it selected?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question fully, but on this link : http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/12.vi/paper-8.html, when they talk about `^]`, they say: `Mnemonically, this command is ''go right to'' (7.3).`

Comment: @saginaw That version of *An Introduction to Display Editing with vi* is a bit updated (they added a new section, so 7.3 should be 8.3). In any case, the relevant section ([*More File Manipulation Commands*](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/viin/paper-7.html#section48)) doesn't mention `^]`, but only `:ta`. I'm going to tag this with `original-vi`, Vim's earliest version I could find (1.4) had this in 1991, so presumably it's a `vi` thing.

Answer (score 3):

`vi` was designed for use with [glass terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Early_VDUs), the [protocols of which](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/what-protocol-standard-is-used-by-terminals/5802#5802) often use many of the control-*x* commands down at [the low end of ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart). Others were reassigned in the move from paper terminals, such as <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> (form feed), which `vi` reinterprets from "form feed" to mean "repaint display" instead, that being more appropriate to a text editor.

Commands like "jump to tag" — <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> — need to be usable in insert mode as well as command mode, so it couldn't use one of the printable ASCII characters. ASCII defines only 32 non-printable characters. Of those left, <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> apparently seemed like the best choice.

These standards go back something like 15 years before `vi` was created, so `vi` had to play within the existing landscape. You can imagine that all the good ones were taken by the time `vi` came on the scene.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the history of the command, but I think of `[` and `]` as previous and next. It's used for many motions. See `help various-motions` for several examples of square bracket motions.

Therefore, `<C-]>` becomes "Control-Next".

`help CTRL-]` describes it as "Jump to the definition". When I'm pairing that's a bit long winded, so I usually say "drill down" instead.

Comment: +1, but I think my answer has more explanatory power. If they'd selected this keystroke purely for mnemonic reasons, they'd surely have been aware that Ctrl-[ is the same as Escape, which they couldn't use for "go back up," as would seem natural. I'll stick with my explanation: even in 1980, they didn't have much choice left for command keystrokes.